# Having trouble updating a live candlestick chart using dash

Tags: javascript, python, flask, plotly, plotly-dash

I hit an api for live updates for crypto financial data, and I want my graph to update each time a new pull comes in from the api (30 seconds).

This is embedded in a function “tick”, which ticks when it hits the api. I’ve had a range of problems when trying to fix this, but currently it will set up the graph, plot 1 candlestick chart in the dataframe, then won’t run the rest of the python code and allow for another “tick”. I believe it's due to it being a bot an in an infinite loop that I can't setup my dash server.

```
def main(argv):

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    html.Div(className='container-fluid', children=
    [
        html.Div(className='row',
                 children=html.Div(dcc.Graph(id='live-graph', animate=True), className='col s12 m12 l12')),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='graph-update',
            interval=30000
        )
    ]),
)
app.run_server(debug=True)

chart = BotChart("poloniex", "USDT_BTC", 10, False)

strategy = BotStrategy()

candlesticks = []
developingCandlestick = BotCandlestick()


while True:
    try:
        developingCandlestick.tick(chart.getCurrentPrice())
    except urllib.error.URLError:
        time.sleep(int(30))
        developingCandlestick.tick(chart.getCurrentPrice())

    if (developingCandlestick.isClosed()):
        candlesticks.append(developingCandlestick)
        strategy.tick(developingCandlestick)
        developingCandlestick = BotCandlestick()

        Lclose, Lhigh, Llow, LOpen, Ldates = developingCandlestick.returnLists()
        print(Lclose)

        stock_df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': Ldates,
                                 'Open': LOpen,
                                 'High': Lhigh,
                                 'Low': Llow,
                                 'Close': Lclose,
                                 })




        @app.callback(
            Output('live-graph', 'figure'),
            events=[Event('graph-update', 'interval')]
        )
        def graph_update():

            data = {
                'data': [{'close': stock_df.Close,
                          'decreasing': {'line': {'color': '#808080'}},
                          'high': stock_df.High,
                          'increasing': {'line': {'color': '#17BECF'}},
                          'low': stock_df.Low,
                          'name': 'Trace 1',
                          'open': stock_df.Open,
                          'showlegend': True,
                          'type': 'candlestick',
                          'uid': '59f45c30-fa3a-459e-bc6d-f4643f4ed55e',
                          'x': stock_df.Date,
                          'yaxis': 'y2'}],
                'layout': {'legend': {'bgcolor': '#F5F6F9', 'font': {'color': '#4D5663'}},
                           'margin': {'b': 30, 'l': 30, 'r': 30, 't': 30},
                           'paper_bgcolor': '#F5F6F9',
                           'plot_bgcolor': '#F5F6F9',
                           'showlegend': True,
                           'titlefont': {'color': '#4D5663'},
                           'xaxis': {'anchor': 'y2',
                                     'gridcolor': '#E1E5ED',
                                     'rangeselector': {'bgcolor': 'rgba(150, 200, 250, 1)',
                                                       'buttons': [{'count': 1,
                                                                    'label': '1m',
                                                                    'step': 'month',
                                                                    'stepmode': 'backward'},
                                                                   {'count': 1,
                                                                    'label': '1y',
                                                                    'step': 'year',
                                                                    'stepmode': 'backward'}],
                                                       'font': {'size': 13},
                                                       'visible': False,
                                                       'x': 0,
                                                       'y': 0.9},
                                     'rangeslider': {'visible': False},
                                     'showgrid': True,
                                     'tickfont': {'color': '#4D5663'},
                                     'title': '',
                                     'titlefont': {'color': '#4D5663'},
                                     'zerolinecolor': '#E1E5ED'},
                           'yaxis': {'gridcolor': '#E1E5ED',
                                     'showgrid': True,
                                     'showticklabels': False,
                                     'tickfont': {'color': '#4D5663'},
                                     'title': '',
                                     'titlefont': {'color': '#4D5663'},
                                     'zerolinecolor': '#E1E5ED'}}
            }

            return data


    app.run_server(Debug=True)
    time.sleep(int(30))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

I want to have the server setup and update every 30 seconds, that is the expected result. Currently it will setup the server, and since the api and the rest of the data occurs after the server is setup, it won't run the rest of the code. Any help is appreciated, and if you think there is a better option to graph live financial data i'm all ears. Thank you in advance!